# Rerun import in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

In jupyter notebook, I have a cell including all imports. Those imports some of my own modules.

When I rerun the cell, it does not pick up the updates in the modules. I need to to a kernel restart and rerun the whole notebook. Is there any other way to fix this problem?

Comment: That's the way imports generally work in Python. You can use IPython's [autoreload](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/extensions/autoreload.html) extension to check if modules have changed and reload them.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the reload magic by placing this in your notebook. It will automatically reload code.

```
%reload_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
```

The only time this may cause confusion is, if you instantiated an object, change the code and then wonder, why the already instantiated object does not have the new functions. Besides this case, it works well.

This question is also asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49326354/911441).